# Write a LINQ in C# to filter max x/y in generic PointF list

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a list contains PointF like:

```
[10.5, 5.5]
[8.5, 4.5]
[10.5, 6.5]
[5.5, 10.5]
[10.5, 3.5]
```

Is it possible to have a LINQ to find the max value of x first and then find the max value of Y from among those max X value to yield the result like:

```
[10.5, 6.5]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
points.OrderBy(i => i.x).ThenBy(i => i.y).Last();
```

or if you preffer LINQ query syntax:

```
(from point in points
orderby point.x, point.y 
select point).Last();
```

Comment: Thanks. LINQ + Lambda is the way to go. It's so elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Following groups by the x-values, takes the highest group and select the highest y value in that group.

```
PointF maxPoint = points
        .GroupBy(p => p.X)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
        .Take(1)
        .Select(g => new PointF(g.Key, g.Max(p => p.Y)))
        .First();
```